# Consider the sequence of functions defined as $ g_n =\int_{0}^{1} x^n f(x)dx$. Show that $ \frac {g_{n+1}}{g_n} \ge \frac {g_1}{g_0}$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

The following problem was given by my friend as a challenge, but unfortunately I was not able to solve.

> Let $f$ be a continuous and non negative real valued function defined on $[0,1]$. Consider the sequence of functions defined as   $ g_n =\int_{0}^{1} x^n f(x)dx$. Show that $ \frac {g_{n+1}}{g_n} \ge \frac {g_1}{g_0}$.

I think this problem is hard (well, at least for me) and i am sorry that i am not getting a way to solve this. Any hints/ideas?

Comment: This is [AMM problem 11855](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.7.700?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). I'm locking the question until the contest is over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $D=[0,1]^2$. We have:

$$g_{n+1}g_0-g_ng_1=\int\int_D x^{n}(x-t)f(x)f(t)dxdt=\int\int_D t^{n}(t-x)f(x)f(t)dxdt$$

Hence adding the two integrals:
$$2(g_{n+1}g_0-g_ng_1)=\int\int_D (x^{n}-t^n)(x-t)f(x)f(t)dxdt$$

And as $(x^n-t^n)(x-t)\geq 0$ for all $x,t$, we get $g_{n+1}g_0-g_1g_n\geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you and +1 of course !